# How to redirect to new page in angular/javascript after posting complex object

Tags: javascript, .net, angularjs

In .NET, when you use a form with POST, you can submit a complex object to a controller action, and that action will return an ActionResult that can direct to any page/view you want.

I need to achieve this effect, but except in angular.

Normally, in angular, I can do AJAX POST with complex object like this

```
// complex object pararmeter: this will come from various input boxes with ng-model
$scope.parameter = { Id: 5, Filter: { Region: "A", District: "B" }};  

$http({
    method: "POST",
    url: "/Student/GetReport",
    data: $scope.parameter
}).success(function (result) {
    // take the json result and do something on this page
});
```

However, this time, I won't hit hitting an action that returns a JsonResult, I will be hitting a normal .NET controller action that returns a View/ActionResult. Then I want the page to redirect to whatever that View/ActionResult is.

**location.href** lets you redirect to an url. But I think it only does GET and does not allow complex object parameter.

Can any expert help me? I don't see why this is not achievable.

Comment: If you return a View from .NET controller action, the result parameter in success call back will usually be HTML markup (partial view), the markup could be set inside div after sanitizing using $sce.trustAsHtml(result);

Comment: @DhananjayaKuppu but i dont want to do anything with the plain html that it returns. Because the action goes to a view that generates an devexpress report using a different layout. If i do a window.open() then append the html, ill just see a bunch of plaintext with no style. And chances are the report won't even be generated.

Comment: @DhananjayaKuppu the idea is that it shouldnt be asynchronous. It should be as if I submitted a form in .NET with complex object and gets redirected to a new view. But I want to achhieve this effect in angular. It just seems like it shouldnt be hard but its proving very difficult for me to find a solution

Comment: so you are generating a view (not a partial view) am I right? And if the devexpress report has its own styles and does not depend on parent page? If it is true for both the questions then have you tried appending the result using JQuery html method? innerHTML might not download styles, script tags that are present in the resulr but JQuery html can do then it may work.